# Windows 8 freezes on startup when intel VT-d is enabled

Tags: windows-8, vt-d

I don't know what to make of this situation:

Windows 8 freezes after about 3 seconds after booting to the log in screen.

The only way i have been able to avoid the freeze, is if i set

- VT-d disabled
- VT-d enabled, but Nvidia drivers uninstalled (running on integrated graphics)
- VT-d enabled, Nvidia drivers installed, Hyper-V feature enabled

My goal is to get Windows 8 running with VMWare (ie. Hyper-V has to stay disabled), VT-d and the latest NVidia drivers.

Specs:

- 32 GB of ram
- Intel Core i7-2760QM
- NVidia Quadro 1000M
- Intel 520 SSD 480GB

Maybe somebody has experience with this kind of a situation ?

Comment: We need more specfic information about the system.

Comment: @Ramhound Updated

Comment: Have you tried an updated the BIOS/UEFI?

Comment: @Ramhound Yeah, did that.

Comment: Even if the HyperV feature is installed, you don't have to use it.  On my Windows 8 setup, the Hyper-V services are set as triggered start.  Meaning that they don't start until the service is needed.  It's possible that something in the setup is used by VMWare, but my only experience is with HyperV.  Have you tried using the WDDM driver for the nvidia card as a test as opposed to the "latest and greatest"?

Comment: do you really need VT-d (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOMMU)?

Answer (score 2):

There are apparently many reasons for freezes in Windows 8.
I list here some of the known fixes, including that of Hyper-V below.

1. [Disable dynamic ticks](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2727113) by doing in CMD as administrator (no known reason why it works) :
   `bcdedit /set disabledynamictick yes`
2. [Disable C-states or C-modes](http://www.eightforums.com/bsod-crashes-debugging/6462-windows-8-freezing-2.html#post97336) if your bios allows it
3. [Activate Hot Swap](http://scottiestech.info/2012/09/01/windows-8-freezes-or-hangs-the-fix-that-worked-for-me/) if your bios allows it by setting it to Enabled
4. Update all drivers, if possible from the manufacturer's website
5. Fully patch Windows, including optional updates
6. Activate Hyper-V (some people report that disabling dynamic ticks solves the same problem)

As regarding Hyper-V, I quote from [Windows 8 Web Browsing Freeze](http://rudiv.se/Blog/general/windows-8-release-preview-browser-freeze-fix) :

> By enabling Hyper-V on your machine, your root OS (which you use) will
>   now run on top of a Hypervisor, which means it's essentially
>   visualised. It's not in the same sense as a virtual machine, as your
>   OS will still have direct hardware access to essentials such as
>   graphics cards for gaming.
>
> If you already run a virtualisation environment such as VMWare or
>   VirtualBox (with 64-bit VMs only), they will no longer work. The
>   reason is that the Hypervisor doesn't expose the VT-x extension to
>   it's virtual machines (including your new root), and so other
>   virtualisation products can't be ran with full effectiveness. The
>   obvious workaround to this problem is to convert your
>   VMWare/VirtualBox VMs to Hyper-V, and import them using the Hyper-V
>   Manager.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. Tried 1, 4 and 5. Couldn't find C-States/C-Modes in BIOS nor the Hot Swap option. Activating Hyper-V is also not applicable due to the VMWare requirement.

Comment: For Hyper-V, I just intended to explain why it conflicts with VMware. Question: Is downgrading to Windows 7 an option?

Comment: Yeah, i'm currently on Windows 7 as the main OS, but have bought Windows 8 as well, so i'd like to get that upgrade going.

Comment: Seeing the number of posts we are already getting here for Windows 8, I believe one should at least wait for SP1.